# Install/replace default android audio decoder - Play Hi-res audio

Tags: root-access, custom-roms, audio, aosp

I want to be able to playback hi-res audio files on my device without being tied to a specific application. According to [this spec page on GSMArena](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s10+-9535.php) the device should be able to play 32-bit audio files. But it seems that this functionality was maybe added to OneUI as the same audio files (24-bit and 32-bit audio) playback with static or stuttering on any AOSP custom rom. Even playing back the audio on other phones, like Pixels, result in the same stuttering. Apps like VLC do support these files flawlessly however it doesn't have the same functionality like closed-sourced apps (example BlackPlayer EX). My question is there anyway to replace the default Android OS audio playback engine or somehow add functionality to support these kinds of files? Or is there any way to add functionality to down-mix the files to 16-bit during playback?

Device: Galaxy S10+ (Exynos)
OS: Evolution X 5.9.1
Root: Magisk

Comment: If your device is rooted, V4a can sample at [higher rates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWt0H.png) apart from a ton of other audiophile modifications. I've had this module running from Android 8 onwards to 11

Comment: @beeshyams Yes, I'm rooted with Magisk. I have both Audio Modification Library and Viper4Android installed. Do you have any instructions or links into how to do that?

Comment: By default or goes to the higher setting. You can join the Telegram group if you need help https://t.me/ViPER4AndroidFX